# maven: how to prevent plugin updates

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988458/maven-is-trying-to-update-glassfish-plugin-from-maven-ocean-net-au), I can't do a glassfish deploy because some server in Australia is down at the moment. I've had the artifacts cached locally for months.

How can I tell maven to not attempt to update the plugin (and its dependencies)? I tried adding the following to my pom, but it didn't help:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
            <id>ocean</id>
            <url>http://maven.ocean.net.au</url>
            <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>
```

I also tried the command line switches. There's `-npu`, which didn't seem to help with Maven 2.2.1.  On Maven 3 the docs say "Ineffective, only kept for backward compatibility", so I don't have a lot of hope for that one.

We will be moving to Nexus soon, but there ought to be a simple way to tell maven not to attempt a plugin update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-o` or `--offline` switch to work offline - this should make Maven not bother to check any repositories for new updates or snapshots, as if you did not have network access.

Additionally - are you specifying the `<version>` for each of your plugins? There should be no need to check for updates to release versions of a plugin.

Comment: I did in fact try "-o". But when used with "glassfish:redeploy" it results in "No such local command, undeploy". I have <version>2.1</version> specified for the maven-glassfish-plugin.

Comment: Doh, if I move the "-o" up to be the first arg on the command line it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven 2 there's a file called [plugin-registry.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-registry.html) where you can specify the version of each plugin. The ugly thing about this file, is that it has to be copied / installed on each box that uses maven (ci server, dev boxes, etc).

The benefit is that you can specify a version, and one it's downloaded, it won't be updated again.

If you migrate to maven 3, this has been sorted out, and you can specify the version you want on the pom.