# Warning during deploying of app with Maven Glassfish plugin

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

I get this warning each time I redeploy the application with the Maven Glassfish plugin. Why? How can I stop that, it takes very long time to deploy.

```
Downloading: http://maven.ocean.net.au/release/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.ocean.net.au/external/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 4.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.ocean.net.au/snapshot/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to release.ocean.net.au (http://maven.ocean.net.au/release): maven.ocean.net.au
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to external.ocean.net.au (http://maven.ocean.net.au/external): maven.ocean.net.au
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to snapshot.ocean.net.au (http://maven.ocean.net.au/snapshot): maven.ocean.net.au
```

Comment: What is the `http://maven.ocean.net.au/`? Do you define somewhere in your `pom`, `parent pom` or `settings.xml`?

Comment: I have no idea what it is, I haven't defined it. It seems like it is the maven glassfish plugin which uses it somehow.

Comment: Please have a look at [Maven is trying to update glassfish plugin from maven.ocean.net.au](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988458/maven-is-trying-to-update-glassfish-plugin-from-maven-ocean-net-au). I hope this may help.

Comment: I am actually using 2.1